# Strange popup update message

Tags: updates, 20.04

This message appears every now and then on my desktop, but I don't really trust it is real.
It is so weird because, when ubuntu is going to update, it gets some more information about what programs it is going to update.
[image]

Somebody knows either it is a real update or a virus? And it is a virus, how to disable it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open up your terminal (`ctrl` + `alt` + `t`) and type `sudo apt upgrade -y` - this will upgrade your packages. From here, see if you get an update.

Comment: Can't remember ever having seen a window with this particular text.

Comment: I did sudo apt upgrade -y, but still happend, Don't know what to do but reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days turning me crazy for answers, finally I've just found a solution, or better said, the reason of that window appears.
It is only an upgrade for lubuntu desktop as I show you on next picture... Time ago, I installed a lubuntu and other flavoures in my ubuntu system and when I activated it that message started appear.

You can see the solution on this link https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.4/Update-Notifier.html

Thank you both DankyNanky and Jos for your anwsers.